# How to find embed iframe url of a website

Tags: javascript

I just want to know how i can find the imbedded url of the video on this site: https://en7.sportplus.live
Or how can I embed videos from this site: (https://en7.sportplus.live) to my blogger/wordpress blog?

Comment: I can't find a video on this site... but you can always try to right-click the video player and click "Inspect" to look for an URL to embed

Comment: This page does not have an `iframe`. And we can't even detect it here due to `noscript` tags.

Comment: Step 1: Talk to the owners of the content. Step 2: Come to an agreement to show their content on your site. Step 3: Work with them to develop the technical solution.

Answer (score 0):

Going through myblogger.com, you can only

1. Import a video(upload from computer)
2. Import/embed from youtube.

Image embedding from various websites is what is available on myblogger.com